# Fitting a Globally Monotonically Increasing Polynomial to Data in Python

Tags: python, optimization, curve-fitting, least-squares

I have a dataset to which I want to fit a nth degree univariate polynomial in a least squares fashion. The resulting polynomial should be monotonically increasing for all real numbers, not just the range of the data. I am using Python.

I've tried using cvxpy to create a problem where I added constraints that the derivative should be non-negative at specific points. This way I can create a polynomial that is monotonically increasing in the range of data, but it won't guarantee that the polynomial is monotonically increasing globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. First of all, the degree of the polynomial must be odd.

Here's how I solved a 5th degree polynomial case:

A polynomial will be monotonically increasing globally if its derivative is a perfect square. In this case the degree of the derivative is 4. A fourth degree perfect square has the form (a*x**2 + b*x + c)**2. We can get a definition for our 5th degree polynomial if we expand this expression and then calculate its integral.

We start with parameters a, b, c, and d. d is serves as a bias parameter. We can then determine the coefficients of the original polynomial like this (the polynomial will be of form `A*x**5 + B*x**4 + C*x**3 + D*x**2 + E*x + F`):

```py
A = a**2 / 5
B = a * b / 2
C = (2 * a * c + b**2) / 3
D = b * c
E = c**2
F = d
```

With these coefficient definitions we can directly fit the polynomial without needing to use any constraints.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question is addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925921/determining-whether-a-polynomial-is-monotonic-on-a-given-interval-i#:%7E:text=If%20all%20roots%20in%20x,then%20the%20polynomial%20is%20monotonic.), where a package in R to do exactly this is discussed (MonoPoly). I don't know of a python implementation, but the R implementation details are available in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00180-012-0390-5).

Depending on your problem, you might also be able to brute force it and compute the derivative everywhere.